# How would you improve this point of interaction between Python and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm writing a checkout form for purchasing online tests.  You can buy a certification or a recertification, as well as a pdf or book study manual.

I'm using Jinja2 templates to provide test data into the Javascript.  The test object is a dictionary with the following structure.  All prices are in cents.

```
test {
    id: Integer,
    name: String,
    acronym: String,
    certification_price: Integer,
    recertification_price: Integer,
    study_pdf_price: Integer,
    study_book_price: Integer,
}
```

If a user buys more than one test, they get a discount of 10% off for each additional test.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calcTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;
        var numTests = 0;
        {% for test in tests %}
            {% if test.certification_price %}
            if ($('#buy-{{ test.acronym }}-certification').is(':checked')) {
                total += {{ test.certification_price }};
                numTests++;
            }
            {% endif %}
            {% if test.recertification_price %}
            if ($('#buy-{{ test.acronym }}-recertification').is(':checked')) {
                total += {{ test.recertification_price }};
                numTests++;
            }
            {% endif %}
            {% if test.study_pdf_price %}
            if ($('#buy-{{ test.acronym }}-pdf').is(':checked')) {
                total += {{ test.study_pdf_price }};
            }
            {% endif %}
            {% if test.study_book_price %}
            if ($('#buy-{{ test.acronym }}-book').is(':checked')) {
                total += {{ test.study_book_price }};
            }
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        // take 10 percent off for each additional test after the first
        if (numTests > 0) numTests--;
        var discountPrice = Math.round(((10 - numTests) * 0.1) * total);

        $('.product-total').html(Math.round(discountPrice));
        $('#final-total').val(discountPrice);
    }
    $('.product-selection').click(calcTotal);
    calcTotal();
});
</script>
<body>
<h2>Selected Products</h2>
<form id="registration-form" action="" method="POST">
    <table id="products-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Add to Cart</th>
        </tr>
        {% for test in tests %}
            {% if test.certification_price %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ test.acronym }} Certification{% if test.study_pdf_price %} (PDF Manual Included){% endif %}</td>
                <td>${{ test.certification_price }}</td>
                <td><input class="product-selection" type="checkbox" id="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-certification" name="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-certification" /></td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if test.recertification_price %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ test.acronym }} Recertification</td>
                <td>${{ test.recertification_price }}</td>
                <td><input class="product-selection" type="checkbox" id="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-recertification" name="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-recertification" /></td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if test.study_pdf_price %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ test.acronym }} {{ test.study_pdf_description }}</td>
                <td>${{ test.study_pdf_price }}</td>
                <td><input class="product-selection" type="checkbox" id="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-pdf" name="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-pdf" /></td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% if test.study_book_price %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ test.acronym }} {{ test.study_book_description }}</td>
                <td>${{ test.study_book_price }}</td>
                <td><input class="product-selection" type="checkbox" id="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-book" name="buy-{{ test.acronym }}-book" /></td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
            <tr><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>$<span class="product-total">0</span></strong></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id="final-total" name="final-total" />
    <p><input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Place Order"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like I am repeating myself a lot, but I don't know how I would do this differently.  Also, this way of providing data by writing Javascript code with the templating language seems messy.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, templating JavaScript code in the way you're doing is messy and usually a bad option. If possible it's almost always better to pass in a single JSON object with all of the values you need and then operate on that object in JavaScript. I don't know Python but something like this:

```
var tests    = {{ json.dumps( tests ) }}, // this is the only template insertion
    total    = 0,
    numTests = 0,
    test,
    testIdPfx
    // only one `var` is necessary for multiple declarations
;

// do this loop in JavaScript instead of the templating system
for ( var i; i < tests.length; i++ ) {
  test = tests[ i ]

  // do this concatenation just once at the beginning
  testIdPfx = '#buy-' + test.acronym + '-';

  // this condition also in JavaScript instead of the template--combined with the
  // `if` you're already doing
  if ( test.certification_price &&
       $( testIdPfx + 'certification' ).is( ':checked' )
     ) {
    total += test.certification_price;
    numTests++;
  }

  if ( test.recertification_price &&
       $( testIdPfx + 'recertification' ).is( ':checked' )
     ) {
    total += test.recertification_price;
    numTests++;
  }

  // and so on...
}

// ...
```

(You could also load the JSON object with an Ajax request and avoid templating in your JavaScript entirely, but that might be overkill.)

Already that looks a lot cleaner but you still have a lot of repetition.

Basically the only thing different between your four `if` blocks is one word: `certification`, `recertification`, `study_pdf` and `study_book`. So why not put those four words in an array and then reuse the same code four times?

```
var tests = {{ json.dumps( tests ) }}, // this is the only template insertion
    // here's your four words:
    types = [ 'certification', 'recertification', 'study_pdf', 'study_book' ]
    total    = 0,
    numTests = 0,
    test, testIdPfx,
    type,
    price
;

for ( var testIdx; testIdx < tests.length; testIdx++ ) {
  test = tests[ testIdx ]
  testIdPfx = '#buy-' + test.acronym + '-';

  // repeat for each of the four words in `types`
  for ( var typeIdx; typeIdx < types.length; typeIdx++ ) {
    type  = types[ typeIdx ];
    // exploit the fact that `test.foo` and `test['foo']` are equivalent in JavaScript
    price = test[ type + '_price' ];

    if ( price && $( testIdPfx + type ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
      total += price;
      numTests++;
    }
  }
}

// ...
```

(**Note:** You'll have to adjust your markup to have `#buy-{{ test.acronym }}-study_pdf` insteady of just `-pdf` and `#buy-{{ test.acronym }}-study_book` instead of `-book` to match the `types` values, or vice versa.)

A nice side-effect of doing the main `for` loop in JavaScript instead of the templating system is that you're sending proportionally less JavaScript code to the client, which saves on bandwidth.

If you wanted you could perform a similar reduction in your markup.

Hope that helps!